# Multiple - Requested registry access is not allowed

Tags: 2013, setup, registry

I'm trying to set up a SharePoint 2013 installation but when I started to configure services I ran in to some issues with registry permission.

The Central Administration Application Pool and SharePoint Timer is running under a account that isn't in the local administrators group, and it seems that it didn't get correct permissions during install.

At first it wanted read permission to `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Office Server\15.0` so I gave it full control on that key and all it's children. After that I got a bit further but now it wants Read/Write on a lot of different Paths.

```
HKCR\APPID\{0FF1CE15-0200-0000-0000-000000000000}
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\.NET CLR Data\Performance
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\.NET CLR Networking\Performance
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Lsa\Performance
...
(about 40 differnt paths so far)
```

Sure I could just grant it permission but it seems like there is a more fundamental issue here.

Comment: i would add that account into local admin group and then reboot the server and test it.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE that would work, however the farm account does not need to be local admin and should not be according to Microsoft Best practise documentation.

Comment: My understanding and also recomend by MSFT, farm account should be Local Administrator on all the SharePoint Servers. SecurityAdmin and DB_Creator rights on the SQL Instance

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, farm account should not be a local administrator when the installation is completed (there is even  rule in Central admin that flags for this)

Comment: that's true but MSFT recommend us to put this account into local admin.

Comment: No, only during installation @WaqasSarwarMCSE, specifically for starting up user profile sync with FIM

Comment: Again i am not saying it is not correct...But in our sitution MSFT recomend us due to alot of issues and we had that account in local admin groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources
```

It is a command that should make sure that services in SharePoint (or, the accounts running them) has correct permissions on registry keys

Comment: Another command that I believe does the same thing is `Initialize-SPResourceSecurity`